# Why does exit(0) cause binder stub implementation NullPointerException to be thrown?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, exit

I am porting my C++ Linux application to Android NDK and have it built, but when I run, I get a java.lang.NullPointerException exception coming from binder stub implementation when I call `exit(0)`.

Why does calling `exit()` cause this failure?  How do I properly give an exit return code for my application when it fails with an error?  What is the android way to do this?

Comment: What is *this* `exit`?

Comment: @user2864740 On linux, the exit() function causes normal process termination and the value of status & 0377 is returned to the parent.

Comment: Not sure but maybe you'd want to call the [`finish`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()) method?

Comment: Is this a proper android application or something like a command line utility?

Comment: @auselen On Linux it is a command line utility, for now I have a simple GUI to set the command line arguments on Android.

Comment: So if you deploy it as a an android application you should follow android application life cycle - android doesn't like exiting ungracefully. Try to invoke your wrapper activity's finish.